# Mercurial hg status shows files I did not modify

Tags: mercurial, terminal

While on terminal I type

```
$ hg status
```

and it shows a list with M and ? which indicates that it is a list of modified files and unknown files, except I did not do anything to those files. 
If I try to revert

```
$ hg revert file/path/filename
```

it does not do anything, those files are not reverted and still listed as modified. 
As for the unknown files with the ? to the left, I just do not know what to do with those files.

By the way, those files in unknown status with the ? are still part of the project.
Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mercurial hg status displaying ignored files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390129/mercurial-hg-status-displaying-ignored-files)

Comment: Have you done a hg diff to see what Mercurial thinks is the difference in the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correctly understanding how things are supposed to work, so whatever is wrong is subtle.  First thing to check: is the (horrible, hateful, broken) inotify extension enabled? You can check with `hg showconfig | grep extensions`.  A few rogue distros enabled that by default and it's a huge problem.

If that's not it what does the output of `hg diff` look like?  What about `hg summary`?  While we're at it what version are you running?

Lastly, are you using a network mounted drive, especially SMB/Windows?  Sometimes window mucks with the execute permissions on file which causes `hg status` to show them as modified in a way that's hard to see using `hg diff`.

Comment: My files are in a Windows VM. The folder is shared and I access it through the Mac Terminal.
What's weird is that after rebooting the Windows VM the files with the ? were gone so I was left with a smaller number of modified files (M). So I ended up doing

    $ hg update -C

and that got rid of the problem.
Weird occurrence, but it almost seemed to have fixed itself.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably the file sharing.  Mercurial works incredibly hard to work well across file sharing, but file sharing tells a lot of very funny file system lies when it comes to small details like access times, number of open file handles, and locking.  I do a similar (mac <-> linux vm) share and I find things work better longer  if I limit my guest-side activities to file edits (not hg or git commands) and do all the hg or git on the host side.  When things get wonky I halt/resume the VM and all's well.

Comment: I am getting file modified, when committing in ms-windows, and then updating in Gnu/Linux (I think it also happens the other way around). I can do a revert, shelve or what ever, but the files are still marked as changed. Any one know why? and how to fix? (always seems to be office docs: files managed by zipdoc)

Comment: FWIW, I got a file on Windows where Mercurial was stuck thinking it was modified, but `hg diff` showed nothing.  No file sharing, Windows only.  `hg revert` did not help.  I could even make a commit, and would get a perfectly empty commit (which I rolled back because I don't want that).  Eventually I found this thread and `hg update -C` worked.  I am using the `eol` extension, so maybe it's related to that.

Answer (score 1):

`hg status` files with a ? are those that Mercurial is not tracking and hasn't been told to ignore.  At the very least the files with ? can be a hint to you that they need to be added to the repository or ignore list.  Depending on your project's structure, untracked files in a `hg status` report are usually just a minor annoyance.  However, make sure that not adding them to Mercurial will not cause problems down the road.